# Powershell How to add a number into a variable

Tags: powershell

how can I add a number to another number contained into a variable?

```
$t0 = Get-date -UFormat "%H%M"
$t1 = $t0 + 10
```

so, if $t0 is 1030, I would $t1 values 1040.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

force to `[int]` before assign value to $t0 ( `get-date -uformat` returns [string] type ):

```
[int]$t0 = Get-date -UFormat "%H%M"
$t1 = $t0 + 10
```

if you change the order the coercing feature of powershell gives the expected value:

```
$t0 = Get-date -UFormat "%H%M"
$t1 = 10 + $t0
```

because second operand is cast to type of first one

Answer (score 4):

This will do it:

```
$t1 = [int]$t0 + 10
```

Answer (score 4):

After doing `$t0 = Get-date -UFormat "%H%M"`, `$t0` does not contain a number, but a String. You can verify this by calling `$t0 | Get-Member`.

One easy way to get around this is to cast it to int:
`[int]$t0 + 10`, which will do normal integer addition.